# R server Error: Peer's Certificate issuer is not recoognized | RSiteCatalyst:: GetReportSuites(). Runs good in Desktop version of R

Tags: r, ssl-certificate, adobe-analytics, rscript, peer

I am pulling data from Omniture sitecatalyst using R.
Packages used:`Rsitecatalyst` using `JSON API` and when I run `GetReportSuites()` in **R server**,  I see the following `error` and it run absolutely fine in desktop version `R`.

> RSiteCatalyst::SCAuth(legacyauth,sharedsecret,company= companyn)

[1] "Credentials Saved in RSiteCatalyst Namespace."

> report_suites <- RSiteCatalyst::GetReportSuites()

Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.

Comment: Why is this tagged python?

Comment: sounds like your rstudio server is using self-signed certificates for https.  Potentially might be answered here: https://community.apigee.com/questions/21954/getting-peers-certificate-issuer-is-not-recognized.html

Comment: This seems less of an R question and more of a network security question.  When you access the RStudio Server on a browser, is there any warning that the connection is unsecure?  If so, it sounds like you `SSL` certificates are self-signed, or your `PEM` file needs modification (or both).  Best advice would be to talk to your RStudio Server Admin.

Comment: Thanks @DaveGruenewald. When accessing Rstudio server on a browser, it does show 'the site is not secure'.

Comment: Figured as much.  Are you the system admin for your Rstudio server? You have three options: 1) change to https for the rstudio server - your admin should be capable to do this; 2) tell `RSiteCatalyst` to ignore the security check - after a cursory glance at I did not see this argument in the package; or 3) continue running on a local instance of RStudio.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @DaveGruenewald again! I tried approaching above options.
1- Our admin is unable to make it "https".
2- tell 'RSiteCatalyst' to ignore the security check- I tried researching but could not find any relevant solution for this. Experts, your inputs will be highly appreciated.
3- This is working well but does not make it fully automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Error does not prevail any more. Possibility is `Rsitecatalyst` ignores the security check and further it is able to fetch the data from Adobe.
Thanks @DaveGruenewald for your thoughts and research.